# Removing a Facebook pixel programmatically

Tags: javascript, facebook, analytics

Is there a way to programmatically remove an instance of a Facebook pixel after initialising it with `fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX')`?

Google analytics.js allows for removing individual tracker objects with `ga('[trackerName.]remove')`, but I can't find any methods on the global fbq object with similar functionality.

Update: While not ideal, a workaround is to target only specific pixels like so:

````
  fbq('init', '<PIXEL_A>');
  fbq('init', '<PIXEL_B>');
  fbq('track', 'PageView'); //fire PageView for both initialized pixels

  // only fire the Purchase event for Pixel A
  fbq('trackSingle', '<PIXEL_A>', 'Purchase', {
        value: 4,
        currency: 'GBP',
  });

  // only fire the custom event Step4 for Pixel B
  fbq('trackSingleCustom', '<PIXEL_B>', 'Step4',{
    //optional parameters
  });```
````

Comment: If this is to protect your users, I wouldn't trust them with that anyway. Just reload the page without the Facebook scripts.

Comment: No it's to enable multiple pixels in a SPA with client side routing where some pixels are only active on certain pages. Atm when you initialise another pixel all default tracking events are sent to all active pixels, with no apparent way to disable/remove individual ones.

Comment: did you manage to find any kind of solution to this problem? cheers!

Comment: Nope unfortunately not. Ended up having to use use the trackSingle method everywhere and making sure only the intended pixel gets the event. Not ideal :(

Comment: How about initializing each pixel in a different script tag, each with a unique ID and then deleting the adequate script tag (by ID) using DOM manipulation? Obviously it's not ideal as well but it's easier to implement imho

Comment: hi @jul have you found the solution, i am experiencing this issue now, or can you share how you do it by "trackSingle method" in your reply

Comment: hi @ArionaRian, please see update with workaround

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? You're not actually disabling pixels, but rather selecting which events are tracked by which pixels. [Selective event tracking with multiple pixels](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/events-advanced-use-cases/v2.12#multipixels)

Comment: Unfortunately not, as the standard tracking events are still being sent to all active pixels.